# Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError - in kayako messenger support tool

Tags: java, android, integration, livechat

I have been receiving this crash tru crashlytics and it says:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError
The list is not sorted by time! Should be in descending order of creation time with newest item on top of list

cant seem to find a way to resolve this since kayako is a third party tool we use for support matters.

Here's the crash logs:

````
       at com.kayako.sdk.android.k5.common.adapter.messengerlist.helper.DataItemHelper.convertDataItemToListItems + 68(DataItemHelper.java:68)
       at com.kayako.sdk.android.k5.messenger.messagelistpage.helpers.MessengerListHelper.getMessageAsListItemViews + 74(MessengerListHelper.java:74)
       at com.kayako.sdk.android.k5.messenger.messagelistpage.MessageListContainerPresenter.generateListItems + 402(MessageListContainerPresenter.java:402)
       at com.kayako.sdk.android.k5.messenger.messagelistpage.MessageListContainerPresenter.displayList + 429(MessageListContainerPresenter.java:429)
       at com.kayako.sdk.android.k5.messenger.messagelistpage.MessageListContainerPresenter.access$000 + 58(MessageListContainerPresenter.java:58)
       at com.kayako.sdk.android.k5.messenger.messagelistpage.MessageListContainerPresenter$8.onSuccess + 715(MessageListContainerPresenter.java:715)
       at com.kayako.sdk.android.k5.messenger.messagelistpage.MessageListContainerRepository$4$1.run + 99(MessageListContainerRepository.java:99)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 873(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 216(Looper.java:216)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7285(ActivityThread.java:7285)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 494(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 975(ZygoteInit.java:975) ```
````

Comment: Please share your code. Especially the part, which fails and fires an error.

Comment: @Steyrix I added the crash log. thank you

Comment: Unfortunately it is not enough to locate the problem. My best suggestion is to try to reproduce the problem, giving some kind of manual monkey-testing to the logic, responsible for using kayako